# Using array to simplify code

Tags: android, android-studio

Because this code is duplicate, I decided to change it

```
TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("ONE");
tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabTwo.setText("TWO");
tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_call, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);

TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabThree.setText("THREE");
tabThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts, 0, 0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabThree);
```

Into :

```
private void SetupTab() {
    TextView[] Tab = new TextView[3];
    int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.tab1,
        R.drawable.tab2,
        R.drawable.tab3
    };
    String[] tabTitle = {"ONE","TWO","THREE"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TextView Tab[i] = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        Tab[i].setText(tabTitle[i]);
        Tab[i].setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, tabIcons[i], 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(Tab[i]);
    }
}
```

But I got problem that my program didn't work. Can anyone help me solve it ? I'm very appreciated with your help.

Comment: Your drawables are not the same

Comment: What do you mean your program doesn't work? Is that SetupTab method called?

Comment: sorry, my fault I mistyped the drawables. Thank you for telling me about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `TextView[] Tab` is unnecessary:

```
private void SetupTab() {
    int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.tab1,
            R.drawable.tab2,
            R.drawable.tab3
    };
    String[] tabTitle = {"ONE","TWO","THREE"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        view.setText(tabTitle[i]);
        view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, tabIcons[i], 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the best solution so far :D Thank you very much :D